# disable other div input field which is not selected

Tags: jquery

i am trying to disable all input fields of some other div which is not selected.

i am able to disable input fields with below code but it works with selected id.

i want to include not 
so that all input fields which are other than selected div are disabled so that when form is submitted those data are not sent

it disables all field for id buyadsellad when selected but i want to do reverse.

```
    $("#buyadsellad :input").prop("disabled", true);
```

here is full code

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="addsite" name="addsite">

  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="sitename">
      <option>Choose Site</option>

      <option value="buyadsellad">buyadsellad</option>
      <option value="ddfdffhtrtttgt5trf">ddfdffhtrtttgt5trf</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="buyadsellad box" id="buyadsellad" style="display: none;"><input type="text" title="" value="667667" name="nottitle" class="txt">
  </div>
 
  <div class="ddfdffhtrtttgt5trf box" id="ddfdffhtrtttgt5trf" style="display: block;"><input type="text" title="" value="9999999" name="nottitle" class="txt"></div>

  </div> <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="txt2">
</form>
```

below is clear picture when buyadsellad option is selected from option dropdown then buyadsellad div is shown and i want to add disable field in all input fields which is not buyadsellad 
. in this case i want to disable input fields in this div ddfdffhtrtttgt5trf

i dont want to give specific name because i dont know no of div in this form may be. in this case its just two div but it may be 20. so i want to disable all input fields other than buyadsellad div

Comment: You have way more closing tags then opening tags.

Comment: @MarkBaijens that is typo but can u plz tell how to use not function in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code is a working version of what you are expecting. By default all input will be hidden. Once you change the select box it will show the input accordingly.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectbox').change(function(){
        var elementid = $('#selectbox').val();
     $('.box').hide(); 
     $("input.form-control").prop("disabled", true);
        $("."+elementid).show().find("input").prop("disabled", false)
        
    });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" id="addsite" name="addsite" style="width: 500px; margin: 50px auto;">
  <div class="form-group">
   <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="selectbox" name="sitename">
    <option>Choose Site</option>

    <option value="buyadsellad">buyadsellad</option>
    <option value="ddfdffhtrtttgt5trf">ddfdffhtrtttgt5trf</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <div class="buyadsellad box form-group" id="buyadsellad" style="display: none;"> 
   buyadsellad : <input type="text" title="" value="667667" name="nottitle" class="txt form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="ddfdffhtrtttgt5trf box form-group" id="ddfdffhtrtttgt5trf" style="display: none;">
   ddfdffhtrtttgt5trf: <input type="text" title="" value="9999999" name="nottitle" class="txt form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="txt2">
  </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Can you add your form html. So I can make a demo for you

Comment: sorry. i did not formatted correctly so it was not visible. added now

Comment: are you trying to show and hide div on the basis of selection ?

Comment: yes. the div which wil l be shown whose input element will be active all others will be disabled

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please use my html. Your html has some opening and closing tag issue. I have corrected them also.

Comment: where u r disabling input field ??? my hide show is working properly. if u r not disabling then it will also be submitted when users clicks on submit

Comment: I have disabled the input field as well. Updated my answer.

Comment: If you feel the answer is correct. Please mark as correct answer.